# How to pass or output data from a ruby script to a node.js script?

Tags: node.js, ruby

I am looking for a way to pass or output data from one script to another script so that the late script can execute itself with the output that came from the first one.

Basically, I have a ruby script with some instructions in it and I want to pass (or output...) the result of the ruby script to a node.js script.

I would like help ( and examples ... ) on how to realize this and/or recommendations for techniques or technologies I might have never heard of it that might do the trick

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) `exec` to execute a script and handle it's output.

### Ruby Script

```
# example.rb
puts "hello world"
```

### Node Script

```
// example.js
const exec = require('child_process').exec

exec('ruby example.rb', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.error(err)
  console.error('stderr: ' + stderr)
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout) // logs "hello world"
});
```

Comment: in this case, does the data flow from the ruby script to the node.js script?

Comment: The ruby script get's executed and whatever is put in `stdout` is picked up by the node script. Let me edit and get you a proper Ruby/Node.js example.

Comment: is there a way to execute the ruby script and pass the result to the node.js script so the data kind of flow unidirectionally from ruby to node ?

Comment: This way is pretty good as well I'll play around with it to see how I might use it.

Comment: This is exactly what happens in the example I've included. Does your Ruby script terminate after outputting it's results? If not, you need to use `spawn` instead.

Comment: yes, it does finish after outputting the result. Thanks, @Nicholas. I'll play around with it. I was also thinking about doing the same thing with socket.io what do you think?

Comment: WebSockets are primarily meant for bidirectional *network* communication. You can communicate between processes with WebSockets as well but it's just not recommended if both processes are running on the same machine.